# Is there any examples of a Banach algebra which every ideal of it, is a maximal ideal?

Tags: ideals, examples-counterexamples, banach-algebras

Is there any examples of a Banach algebra which every  ideal of it, is maximal ideal?

Or, 
Is there any conditions which turn all of the ideals of a Banach algebra to maximal ideals?

Comment: Are these commutative or noncommutative Banach algebras? If the latter, do you mean left, right, or two-sided ideals? Presumably you're excluding the unit ideal, but are you also excluding the zero ideal?

Comment: Yes, I exclude the zero ideal and the unit ideal. Also I mean '' closed''  two sided ideals...By adding commutative condition we can see this problem easier ...Thus consider this problem for commutative Banach algebra...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider the reals under multiplication and addition. Then the only proper ideal is $0$. Thus every proper ideal is maximal.

Comment: Thanks...but I need to nontrivial cases...In general,can you see an answer ?

Comment: I mean infinite dimensional Banach algebras....Thanks